# Don't understand ClassTag and Array Creation

Tags: scala

ClassTag only keeps the top level type of the type parameter, that is, given the following type: `Seq[List[Int]]`,the type parameter is `List[Int]`, but Only `List` is kept and `Int` is lost

```
def mkArray[T: ClassTag](data: T*) = Array(data: _*)
val data = Seq(List(1), List(2), List(3))
val arr = mkArray(data)
```

When calling `mkArray` to create an array, the `Int` for `List[Int]`should have been lost, so why the created array has the correct type of its elements,which is List[Int]

Comment: one possible explanation is you are wrong about "it should have been lost" ... Have you considered that? Like "duh ... no, it shouldn't"

Answer (score 2):

The underlying Java array knows the erased type of its elements at runtime. The compiler knows the precise time at compile-time.

```
scala> val xs = Array(List(1))
xs: Array[List[Int]] = Array(List(1))

scala> xs.getClass.getComponentType
res0: Class[_] = class scala.collection.immutable.List

scala> val vs = xs.asInstanceOf[Array[List[String]]]
vs: Array[List[String]] = Array(List(1))

scala> vs(0) = List("hi")

scala> xs
res2: Array[List[Int]] = Array(List(hi))
```

Answer (score 0):

That information is lost at runtime, from type erasure, but not at compile time.

Comment: Thanks @joe-k, but array creation happens at runtime?

Comment: Array creation happens at runtime, but an array does not need to know what type of objects it is storing in order to store them. Technically at runtime it just holds memory addresses.

Comment: Thanks @joe-k. regarding to your your explanation, it leads to me to think that ClassTag isn't needed at all, since the created array only holds memory address.Sorry if I am heavy-headed, but I really didn't understand well.